# jquery create simple image slideshow animation - fade in and out image

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

i am creating a custom image slideshow, i do not want to use some plugin. I want to create image transitions, just simple fade out and next image fade in. The slider just works by appending the image in parent.

```
<div class="img-holder">
    <img src="/img/slide1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I have a list of images that i fetch with ajax, and on nav click i append next or prev image instead of this one.

Simple example is in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YX9Km/3/)

How can i fade in the image i append? or make different animation on it if i chenge my mid, but primary fade in.

Answer (score 0):

Could you swap out the images src instead of removing / appending and then just fade it back in?

So...
- fade out image
- swap out src
- fade in image

If you put the effects in their own function, you could just swap them out.

I've updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YX9Km/7/

```
/* var effectBefore = function(el, speed, callback) {
    el.animate({ opacity: 0}, speed, callback);
};

var effectAfter = function(el, speed) {
    el.animate({ opacity: 1}, speed);
}; */

var effectBefore = function(el, speed, callback) {
    el.animate({ height: 0 }, speed, callback);
};

var effectAfter = function(el, speed) {
    el.animate({ height: 100 }, speed);
};

$('.next-img').click( function(){
    var imgEl = $(".img-holder img");
    effectBefore(imgEl, 400, function() {
        imgEl.attr('src', 'http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png');
        effectAfter(imgEl, 400);
    });
});
```